# VBA - moving Sharepoint table with attachments to local tables

Tags: ms-access, vba

We are working on archiving data from multiple linked sharepoint tables to local access tables. However they have attachment fields so we are getting the multifield error when our vba is running the Select into statement.  Is there a way around this and also preserve the attachment as well? Is there another way to convert the tables with out the select into statement that would be better?  I checked but the other questions about this did not have this specific issue.

Answer (score -1):

You did not post if you have anything in attachments fields and if you are trying to preserve data in them.

If not, simply use append query to move data to local table, with selected fields, excluding attachment fields.

Comment: Lol. Yeah. I wouldn't have asked how to preserve the attachments if I didn't need them... :(

Comment: I just did test on our test share point site, and I was able to import table, and append to existing table records with attachement.

Comment: And it had attachments in it?

Comment: Yes, you can see it on image - table is imported to local database, with attachments.

Comment: Cool. How did you do it with vba. My select into statement falied

Comment: Easiest way is to import list with VBA ( [link](http://i65.tinypic.com/rrti8l.jpg) )